# Encoding error on nginx when using a regexp on location and a proxy_pass

Tags: regex, nginx, encoding, utf-8, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to have a reverse proxy with nginx to show as local images, the ones that I have on a AWS cloudfront.

To do that, I've added a new location for that files, and It's working.

The problem is when the image has non-ascii characters. I've set the encoding as utf-8 but, when asking to cloudfront, nginx gives the special characters as ??

This is my site conf:

```
source_charset utf8;
charset utf8;
server {
  listen 80; 
  root /srv/app/;
  server_name _;
  client_max_body_size 50M;
  location ~* "(*UTF8)/content/images/(?<image>.+)$" {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass https://my_distribution.cloudfront.net/$image;
  }
}
```

I've got everything on en_US.utf-8.

This nginx is running in a nginx-alpine docker. This is the Dockerfile:

```
ROM nginx:stable-alpine

ENV TERM="xterm"

RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates wget && \
    wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/master/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
    wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.25-r0/glibc-2.25-r0.apk && \
    wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.25-r0/glibc-bin-2.25-r0.apk && \
    wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.25-r0/glibc-i18n-2.25-r0.apk && \
    apk --no-cache add glibc-bin-2.25-r0.apk glibc-i18n-2.25-r0.apk glibc-2.25-r0.apk

RUN /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

How can I debug this? How can this be fixed?

Thanks!